# Why Vepsa easily warning me " This may lead to recall and ranking issues."

Tags: vespa

I am doing parent-child mode, but when i deploy, vespa warn lots of my fields about "This may lead to recall and ranking issues."

finally I found that, i easy the problem to just one sd file

```
search vp001 {
    document vp001 {
        field saleno type string {
            indexing: attribute | summary
            attribute: fast-search
        }
        
        field salename type string {
            indexing: attribute | summary
            attribute: fast-search
        }
    }
    
    fieldset default {
        fields: saleno, salename
    }
}
```

if I change saleno type from string to int, vespa will warning me again

```
Uploading application package ... done

Success: Deployed myproject
WARNING For schema 'vp001', field 'saleno': The matching settings for the fields in fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues.
WARNING For schema 'vp001', field 'saleno': The normalization settings for the fields in fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues.
WARNING For schema 'vp001', field 'saleno': The stemming settings for the fields in the fieldset 'default' are inconsistent (explicitly or because of field type). This may lead to recall and ranking issues.
```

Why ? Do I need to make sure all fileds in filedset to be the same type ?    And I found that I cannot mixed "index" and "attribute" filed in fieldset, if i do so, the warning will appear too.

If not the same type, the warning appear, what ranking issues will happen ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you see this warning whenever you put fields with different kinds of tokenization in the same fieldset. This is because a given piece of text searching one fieldset is tokenized just once, so there's no right choice of tokenization in this case.

Attributes and text indexes are tokenized differently (exact match vs. tokenized match), so you'll see this then.

In most cases you know whether a given text should match an unstructured text field (a string index field), or some structured data, so doing this is just an error. Otherwise, you need to use query expansion instead of a fieldset: Expand the query to search these fields separately, either on the client side, or in a Searcher component.

Comment: I don't want to use attribute to search, but i need parent-child mode, so i cannot avoid to use attribute field.   But what I want to know is that, if i mix these two kinds field in fieldset, what ranking issue will happen ?     and what means recall issue ?   Will this cause my search ranking or results wrong ?

Comment: Indexed strings are tokenized, so e.g the string "foo bar." becomes two tokens "foo" and "bar", which means you can match them by querying for "foo" and/or "bar". Attributes are not so you can only match it by querying for "foo bar." exactly (or a prefix/regexp). If you put both in the same fieldset, should the query be tokenized to match "foo" and "bar" separately, or search for the string "foo bar."? It can only do one or the other and then will only recall one field or the other. Since fields imported from parents cannot be indexed, such fields do not support unstructured text match.

Comment: does this means the two behavor cannot be happend together, so "recall" means search index fields will be one time, and again to search attribute fields, and vespa will merge two results ?

Comment: sorry I still cannot understand "recall" means  >"<

Comment: When you use a fieldset, Vespa will *not* query twice (with different tokenizations) and merge the results. It will just query once, and pick one of the tokenizations, hence the warning. ("Recall" just means "documents matched": You'll miss some matches when you get this warning.)

Comment: But I cannot miss some matches that we want, how to avoid this ?

Comment: I had try to keep all fields be the same type, example, let "price" to be string
but soon i found that it cannot be sorting correctly, and cannot be searched by => IntItem price:[200;400]

so i had to change the "price" field back to int, but if this will casue above you said, some matches will missed, I will be killed by my boss !!

Comment: Three ways to solve this: 1) Write a Searcher to expand the query to search multiple fields with different tokenization (not sure it is reasonable to assume that any number in a query might be a price, but for other cases this would make sense.) 2) Use a semantic rule base to do the same. 3) Add another field just for matching by anything and put the various source fields in that. This can be done a) in the schema by adding a field outside the document and writing an indexing statement taking input from multiple fields, b) in a document processor, or c) outside Vespa where you create the feed.